# MySql: Adding not null constraint to column with null values passes?

Tags: mysql, sql, junit

I have a JUnit test for some mysql code which passes locally but fails when run on the server.
Locally I am using Windows 7 and the server is Ubuntu 14.04. Both are running MySql 5.6.

I have a char column with a null value and try and put a not null constraint on it. Locally this fails as it should but on the server I only get a warning but it passes and the null value is set to a empty string. (See images)
I assume this is some difference in mysql server configuration?
I am new to MySql and can't find how to fix this.

Example image: up is server, down is local:

[image: Example image: up is server, down is local]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

You probably get:

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES/STRICT_ALL_TABLES


UP env :   -------
DOWN env:   STRICT_..._TABLES
```

The difference is **Error vs Warning**:

[image]

[Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html):

> Strict mode controls how MySQL handles invalid or missing values in
>   data-change statements such as INSERT or UPDATE. A value can be
>   invalid for several reasons. For example, it might have the wrong data
>   type for the column, or it might be out of range. A value is missing
>   when a new row to be inserted does not contain a value for a non-NULL
>   column that has no explicit DEFAULT clause in its definition. (For a
>   NULL column, NULL is inserted if the value is missing.)

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9723d/2/0)**</kbd>

The correct way to solve it is first to update `NULL` to empty string before altering schema.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(primary_key INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                        short_char CHAR(100));

INSERT INTO test_table(short_char)
VALUES (NULL);

UPDATE test_table
SET short_char = ''
WHERE short_char IS NULL;

ALTER TABLE test_table modify short_char char(100) not null;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c10ff/2/0)**</kbd>

I recommend to use `VARCHAR(100)` instead of `CHAR(100)`.

Comment: I want it to fail unless it is handled as you wrote in your answer (the correct way).
My local mySql server is running in: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
and the the one on the server is running in:  NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
So I guess that changing the mode on the server to the same one I have locally will fix the problem (I can't try it out straight away because other people need the one on the server).
I found the page about setting the mode: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html
so I geuss the problem is solved.
Thank you for your help.